# Inference test when data points are means

Tags: statistical-significance, mean

#### General background

I've administered two types of questions to students multiple times. Type 1 I've administered six times, and type 2 I've administered five times. The two questions get at the same basic idea but in different ways. Each "question" is just a single multiple-choice question; students provide just one answer (i.e., a single bubble on a Scrantron sheet).

I know the percentage correct on each administration of each question. That is, my data looks something like (35%, 32%, 24%, ...) for one of the questions and (20%, 24%, ...) for the other. I have a total of about 11 data points split into two categories.

#### Question

I want to know if students perform better on one type of question as compared to the other. Is there an inference test or class of tests that are appropriate here?

#### Possibly important details

- A **different number of students** is involved with each administration, but they're all between 60 and 180.
- From other information I know that repeated administrations of the same question result in a gaussian distribution when looking at percentage correct.
- The standard deviations associated with the distributions just mentioned depend greatly on the particular question being asked (presumably due to differences in student backgrounds, etc.) Thus, I don't want to assume or prescribe some type of $\sqrt{Np(1-p)}$ or other standard deviation to each administration.

#### What I've considered

My initial inclination is to do some type of "weighted" t-test, but I couldn't find anything. Then I went down the route of looking at meta-analysis tests, but I'm quite unfamiliar with these.

Are there inference tests that are meant to address this particular situation?

Comment: If the number of questions on each test are the same, I think there are two options available. You can use the paired t-test. Another option is to simply take the difference in means, i.e. create a new column that just looks at the difference (35%-20%, 32-24%,...) and do a Z test for that with the null hypothesis that the mean is zero. The sticking point is to have the same number of questions on both Type 1 and Type 2 because otherwise it doesn't work.

Comment: Each "question" is just a single multiple-choice question. I'll add this to the post.

Comment: I understood that. What I meant was that each test type should have the same number of questions. In other words, Test of difficulty level A can't have more/fewer questions than the test of difficulty level B. If it did, then you difference column can't be computed properly because you'd have numbers left over.